# Continuously input lines using getline to end of txt document C++

Tags: c++, input, getline

I have a really long .txt file which I want to stream in using `getline`. I want to input this entire text document, and then run it through a procedure.

I then want to run that new string through the same procedure using a different values, and so on 2 more times.

So far I have

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void flag(string & line, int len);
void cut(string & line, int numb);

int main()
{
    string flow;
    ifstream input;
    ofstream output;
    input.open(filename.c_str()); //filename ...

    output.open("flow.txt");

    while (!input.fail())
        getline(input, flow);
    flag(flow, 10);
    flag(flow, 20);
    cut(flow, 20);
    cut(flow, 3);

    output << flow;

    return 10;
}
//procedures are defined below.
```

I am having troubles running the entire file through a procedure. How would I stream this in, using `getline`.

I have tried `getline`, `infile.fail`, `npos`, etc.

Comment: Remove the `return` statement.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain: Why ?! the `return` is not inside the `loop`.

Comment: @MM. This is why you should always use `{}`!

Comment: @AlexChamberlain: Yes it's better to use use `{}` and indenting the code, but it's irrelevant to remove the `return`.

Comment: @MM. Yes, but that's why I misread it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
while(!input.fail())
getline(input, flow);
flag(flow, 10); 
flag(flow, 20); 
cut(flow, 20);
cut(flow, 3);
```

you probably want this:

```
while(getline(input, flow)) {
    flag(flow, 10); 
    flag(flow, 20); 
    cut(flow, 20);
    cut(flow, 3);
}
```

Unless I misunderstood you and you want first read the entire file and then call `flag` and `cut`. In that case, you need to *append* the strings you read:

```
string data;
while(getline(input, flow))  data += flow + '\n'; // add the newline character
                                                  // because getline doesn't save them

flag(data, 10); 
flag(data, 20); 
cut(data, 20);
cut(data, 3);
```

Note that `getline` overwrites the string you pass to it.

Also, `while (!input.fail())` is a bad form of loop condition. It might happen that there isn't any more input avaliable but the stream still isn't in a fail state. In that case the last iteration would process invalid input.

Comment: Would your first solution read one line at a time, and run it through each procedure as it goes along?

Comment: @user2162690 Yes, exactly.

Comment: I am supposed to run the entire .txt file through the first procedure, then run that through the second procedure, and so on. Is that your second case?

Comment: Yes. The problem with your code is that it doesn't save the file, it just reads it line by line, overwrites `flow` each iteration and eventualy leaves you with just the last line.